# Group characters and form a matrix in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have 26 characters A to Z, I group 4 characters together and separate the following 4 characters by a space which is like this:

```
abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst uvwx yz
```

My Matlab coding is as follows:

`str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';`

`fstr = [repmat('%c', 1, 4) ' '];`

`A=fprintf(fstr, str);`

Problem: I wish to make it a new line when there are 8 characters in a row which is like this:

```
abcd efgh
ijkl mnop
qrst uvwx
yz
```

Any ideas to do this? Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: `A` is just `32`. You need to fix that first.

Comment: If you "got" it, why not edit the question. As it stands, it will only confuse future readers, with you claiming `A` as `str` padded with spaces after every 4 characters and that isn't what the code in your question does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code ( an approach with [`vec2mat`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/vec2mat.html)) -**

```
%// Input
input_str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' %// Input

%// Parameters
group_numel = 4;
num_groups_per_row = 2;

str1 = vec2mat(input_str,group_numel)
str2 = [str1,repmat(' ',size(str1,1),1)]
output_str = vec2mat(str2,(group_numel+1)*num_groups_per_row)
```

**Code run -**

```
>> input_str
input_str =
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
>> output_str
output_str =
abcd efgh 
ijkl mnop 
qrst uvwx 
yz
```

Comment: Hi @Divakar, this is exactly what i want. Amazing. Your coding is short and simple. Thanks a million for your help.

Comment: Hi @Divakar, I wonder why Approach#1 doesn't work. As I mentioned just now I have A='abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst uvwx yz'. Since I have input same as urs, why there is no output.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use `regexp`

```
A='abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst uvwx yz';
A_splited=regexp(A, '\S\S\S\S\s\S\S\S\S', 'match')
```

However, the last 'yz' will not appear in this case. So there will be a need to tweak using something like this.

```
A_splited{1,end+1}=A(end-rem(length(A),10)+1:end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using regular expressions:

```
str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
str = regexprep(str, '(.{4})', '$1 ');
str = regexprep(str, '(.{4} .{4}) ', '$1\n');
```