# Group Binary and add a space after 8 numbers Matlab (Duplicate)

Tags: string, matlab, matrix, binary, mp3

I wish to group 8 binary numbers together and then shape it into matrix which is as shown:

```
01001001  10110100  10111101  10000111
10110101  10100011  10110010  10111000
010
```

My input will be a MP3 file.

I manage to add a space after 8 binary, but have no idea how to make it to new line after 4 groups of 8 binary.

My Matlab programming is:

```
fid=fopen('mp3file.mp3','r','b');
x=uint8(fread(fid,'ubit1'));
a = 1;

if ( a+100 <= numel(x) )
    B = x(a:a+25);
    str = [repmat('%d', 1, 8) ' '];
    fprintf(str,B);
end
```

---

```
output: 01001001  10110100  10111101  10000111  10110101  10100011 ...
```

I found there is similar post as this, but that one only apply to characters/alphabet, not binary :(

Any ideas?

Comment: Ultimately you are converting your numbers into strings (characters). So this question [group-strings-and-form-a-matrix-in-matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28230187/group-strings-and-form-a-matrix-in-matlab) may give you some inspiration as to how to reshape your final string.

Comment: @Hoki, I did try for the method that u mention. My problem is, `numel(output)=1`. My output array cannot be counted. As a result, there is error: `Undefined function 'regexprep' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.`.

Comment: You need to convert your input to `char` first! Try something like `x = char(x+'0');` before applying `regexprep`.

Comment: @LuisMendo, I got it. Truly appreciate your help :-)

Comment: Is your problem completely solved? Shall we close this question as duplicate of the one linked by Hoki?

Comment: @LuisMendo, this post provides alternative solutions, do I really need to delete this question?

Comment: @Cyan No, I don't think so. I didn't mean to delete it, just mark as duplicate. But I'm not sure it's really a duplicate.

Comment: @LuisMendo , alright, I agree that it is a duplicate and I have stated in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is probably a nice way to do that with regular expression, but I am more comfortable with `reshape` so here is a solution with that.

Also I am not sure of your way of reading your file (your read bit by bit but then you cast it into a `uint8`). Why not directly reading `uint8` ?

So the sequence is: read all the bytes (`uint8`) in the file, convert to char with the [`dec2bin`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html) function, then reshape into the number of column you specify (with a litle twist to add the whitespace in the middle).

It goes:

```
%% // read the file byte by byte (8 bits at a time)
fid = fopen('dice.png','r','b');
x = fread(fid,'*uint8') ;
fclose(fid);                        %// don't forget to close your file

%% //  pad the end with 0 if we don't have a multiple of nByteColumn
nByteColumn = 4 ; %// your number of columns

nByte     = length(x) ;                             %// total number of byte read from the file
nByte2pad = nByteColumn-mod(nByte,nByteColumn) ;    %// number of byte to add to get a full array
x = [x ; zeros( nByte2pad , 1 , 'uint8' ) ];        %// do the padding

%% // now convert to alphanumeric binary (=string) and reshape to your liking
S = [repmat(' ',nByte+nByte2pad,1) dec2bin(x)].' ; %'// convert to char and add a whitespace in front of each byte/string
S = reshape( S , nByteColumn*9 , [] ).' ;          %'// reshape according to your defined number of column 
S(:,1) = [] ;                                      %// remove the leading whitespace column
```

You obtain a `char` array containing all your values shaped in the number of column you specified:

```
>> S(1:3,:)
ans =
10001001 01010000 01001110 01000111
00001101 00001010 00011010 00001010
00000000 00000000 00000000 00001101
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `x` contains the data such that each element of the array is a number 0 or 1, this code does the trick:

```
xs = char('0' + x);
xs = [xs , repmat(' ', 1, 8 - mod(numel(x), 8))];
xs = reshape(xs(:), 8, [])';
xg = cellstr(xs);
fprintf('%s %s %s %s\n', xg{:})
fprintf('\n')
```

---

Line-by-line commentary:

Convert the integer array into a char array (as pointed out by Luis Mendo) a.k.a a string:

```
xs = char('0' + x);
```

This uses "ASCII arithmetic": The symbols '0' and '1' are in sequence in the ASCII code table.

Pad the string with spaces to a multiple of 8:

```
xs = [xs , repmat(' ', 1, 8 - mod(numel(x), 8))];
```

Here `8 - mod(numel(x), 8)` computes how many spaces are necessary to make the string length a multiple of 8.

Use `reshape` to form 8-digit groups:

```
xs = reshape(xs(:), 8, [])';
```

After this, `xs` is a two-dimensional character array, with one 8-bit digit group per row.

Print using `fprintf`:

```
xg = cellstr(xs);
fprintf('%s %s %s %s\n', xg{:})
fprintf('\n')
```

The conversion to a cell array via `cellstr` is necessary so that fprintf can be fed each row as a separate parameter, each matching one of the `%s` in the format string. The additional newline is necessary because it might be that the last output line is not complete.